# save a image in grails

Tags: image, grails, grails-2.0

I have a field for image from which I want to save image to database. But it is showing casting exception. Can anyone please help me on this please? I am using grails 2.1.0. here is my code below :

my view page >>>

```
<g:uploadForm action="upload">

Photo: <input name="photo" type="file" />
<g:submitButton name="upload" value="Upload"/>
```

my controller action >>>

```
def upload={
  def user = User.findById(1)
     user.avatar = params.photo
     user.save()
}
```

my domain class >>>

```
   class User {

    String username
    byte[] avatar
    String avatarType

    static constraints = {
        avatar(nullable:true, maxSize: 1024 * 1024 * 2 /* 2MB */)
        avatarType(nullable:true)
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting? a stacktrace would be nice.

Comment: @ErikPragt I am getting this error >>  "Cannot cast object 'org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile@709e6c86' with class 'org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile' to class 'byte'"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because people can upload more than one file with a single input, I do this to make sure I only get one file.

```
CommonsMultipartFile file = params.list("photo")?.getAt(0)
```

Then you can easily do:

```
user.avatar = file?.bytes
```

Comment: your solution works. Thanks. But how can I check that it is a image file and then save it? Can you help me please?

Comment: I don't know of a way to check if it is an image file other than looking at the extension. `FileNameUtils.getExtension(file?.originalFileName)`

Answer (score 2):

Try this in controller action,

```
def upPic1 = request.getFile('photo')
user.avatar=upPic1.getBytes()
```

The exception came because of casting CommonsMultipartFile into Byte.So convert into bytes then store it.

Comment: if I use this then it shows >>  "can not resolve symbol getFile"

Comment: I didn't import anything.Just try this to import.                import org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile

Comment: Yes but is there any way for using getFile() here

Comment: if u dont want to use getFile, use like <input name="avatar" type="file" />.change the controle name photo into avatar.then in controller action create obj like def user=new User(params).Automatically image is stored as bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
if(request instanceof MultipartHttpServletRequest) {
    MultipartHttpServletRequest mpr = MultipartHttpServletRequest)request;
    CommonsMultipartFile f = (CommonsMultipartFile) mpr.getFile("myfile");
    if(f && !f.empty){
        user.avatar = f.bytes
    }
}
```